# Configuring DNS to resolve to WAMP Virtual Host?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, alias, wamp, cname

I have a website set up on a VM using WAMP. That VM is on a network with an internal domain 123.net. In DNS, I've configured a CNAME (site.123.net) to point to the VM. However, when I try site.123.net, I get a 403 Forbidden error (its a wamp error, so its hitting wamp) What is the next step to configure it so that when I type site.123.net, it goes straight to the website?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to access the site? Outside from home? Then you need bridged networking in the VM. So it gets it's own IP. Then you need to port forward :80, :443 from your router to this new VM IP. Do you just want to reach it via "123.net" from YOUR PC? Then you just need to use `hosts` file. 

**I would have posted an Answer but the question is not clear.**

Comment: sorry, yes, just need to access it internally, not from outside the internal network. What should my hosts file have in it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to reach the host internally only**, you just use a `hosts` file.
Open `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file with Notepad++, and add a new line:

`1.2.3.4       123.net`

So IP comes first, then a space/tab and the domain you want. That's it. Save and it already will work just fine.

**What if I don't have Notepad++?**
Copy out the hosts file to Desktop or any other normal location. Make your edit, then copy it back. This is required because the file is a system file, so you'd have to be an administrator to change it, but notepad will NOT launch as admin by default.

**What if I use Linux/BSD?**
Just add the same format entry into `/etc/hosts`

**What if it's a subdomain?**
`1.2.3.4    subdomain.123.net`

Comment: Thanks! Any idea what the IP address 1.2.3.4 should be? Is that the IP of the VM?

Comment: also, should the url include the subdomain as well? ie:

1.2.3.4  site.123.net?

Comment: @user374369 - Yes, of course, the url must be complete. With sub-domain and everything. Otherwise your PC has no clue what you mean and will ask the DNS server to look it up.

Comment: great. so the IP should be of the virtual machine? or localhost? Thanks for your help!

Comment: tried the IP of the VM and site.123.net as URL.. restarted wamp services (incl. Apache).. same 403 error..

Answer (score 1):

> I get a `403 Forbidden` error (it's a WAMP error, so its hitting WAMP). What is the next step to configure it so that when I type `site.123.net`, it goes straight to the website?

WAMP is intended for local development. If you want to access WAMP from another computer (even on your local network), you will likely need to edit the settings for Apache.

The key directive to look for is the [Require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) directive, which can moderate access to a virtual host (your website). For example, in WAMP, you may have something similar to the following for the default `localhost` virtual host:

*ex. httpd-vhost.conf*

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

*In WAMP 3.2.0, this file would typically be located under e.g. `c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf`.*

---

In this case, `Require local` means that only the local computer (`127.0.0.1`, `::1` or `localhost`) would be allowed to connect to the host named `localhost` on port 80.

To change this to allow *any* computer to connect to this virtual host, you would use `Require all granted` instead:

*ex. httpd-vhost.conf (`Require all granted`)*

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is not the only option, however. For instance, `Require` can also take partial IPs:

```
# Limit host access to client IPs starting with 192.168.1.x
Require 192.168.1
```

The link already given above and the [official Apache documentation for mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html) also have other `Require` examples you may find useful as well.

---

*You should thoroughly check your Apache configuration for `Require` directives. Beyond ex. `httpd-vhost.conf` and any virtual host(s) for e.g. `example.com` and `123.example.com`, the Apache `httpd.conf` file under ex. `c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/httpd.conf` is another important configuration file to look at, since it controls global settings for the server.*

*If the advice given above doesn't work, you may need to make more changes to your virtual host, or may even want to rethink your DNS approach. Subdomains aren't often CNAMEs.*

---